# Angular 2 Reload Window then navigate to different page

Tags: angular, routes

I am working on an app where a logged in user can switch accounts. Whenever they switch accounts, the page needs to reload to get back a new list of capabilities, they then need to navigate to the home page. The home page is dependent on what capabilities the user has, so the reload needs to be done before the router navigate. is there any way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reftesh page with

`window.location.href="here your path"`

it will navigate with refreshin page but it clears session so u can try dummy parametere to refresh it

```
this.router.navigate(["/same/route/path?refresh=1"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can reload the page ok, but i want to carry out a router.navigate once the page has reloaded. I can't do the router.navigate before the page reload

Comment: Did u try window.location.href="path" ?

Comment: if you're using Angular you should take a look at https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Just tried window.location.href. That works! Thanks @Çağrı

Answer (score 0):

@BrianM, there're an aproach that is using a Subject and subscribe in your home component.

Imagine you has in a service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  public observable=this.subject.asObservable();
  changeData(data:any)
  {
     this.subject.next(data)
  }
}
```

In ngOnInit of home you subscribe

```
constructor(private service:MyService){}
ngOnInit()
{
    this.service.observable.subscribe(res=>{
        ..make something with the data...
    })
}
```

When you change the account in a component that inject in constructor the service you only need make a

```
   service.changeData(data);
```